# NullPointerException exception on file uploading in struts2

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, struts2

I am working on struts2 application where i have to upload file and save it into database.
but each time it is showing **NullPointerException** my code is here

**Stack trace is-**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    dao.Clientdao.registration(Clientdao.java:31)
    action.client.Clientaction.execute(Clientaction.java:18)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:314)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

**model class is**

```
import java.io.File;
public class Clientmodel {
private String Aggrement;
private String  date;
private String rate;
private String maturitydate;
private String detail;
private String taxno;
private File imagefile;
public File getImagefile() {
    return imagefile;
}

public void setImagefile(File imagefile) {
    this.imagefile = imagefile;
}

public String getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(String rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public String getDetail() {
    return detail;
}

public void setDetail(String detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}

public String getTaxno() {
    return taxno;
}

public void setTaxno(String taxno) {
    this.taxno = taxno;
}

public String getAggrement() {
    return Aggrement;
}

public void setAggrement(String aggrement) {
    Aggrement = aggrement;
}



public String getMaturitydate() {
    return maturitydate;
}

public void setMaturitydate(String maturitydate) {
    this.maturitydate = maturitydate;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

}
```

**struts.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
       <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"/>
             <constant name="struts.devmode" value="true"/>
             <package name="loginmodel" extends ="struts-default">

        <action name="clientlogin"  class="action.client.Clientaction" >
           <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="allowedTypes">text/plain</param>
            <param name="maximumSize">10240</param>
        </interceptor-ref> 
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>

            <result name="input">/Registration/clientregistration.jsp </result>
           <result name ="success">/Registration/success.jsp  </result>

          </action>

         </package>
</struts>
```

**clientregistration.jsp**

```
<%@ page language ="java" contentType ="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding ="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri ="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri ="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />
<style>
   div.ui-datepicker {
      font-size: 82.5%;
       }
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>CLIENT</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/emp.css">
</head>
<body >

<div id ="did" align="center"> <h1 style="color: red">  CLIENT REGISTRATION FORM</h1>
  <s:form action ="clientlogin" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<s:select  name="Aggrement" label ="Type of Aggrement" list ="{'ORAL', 'written'}  "/>
<sj:datepicker  name="date" label="Aggrement DATE" changeMonth="true" changeYear="true"/>

 <s:select name ="rate" list="{'1','2','3'}" label ="Aggrement rate"/>
<s:textarea  name ="detail" label ="Aggrement Detail"></s:textarea>
 <s:textfield name ="taxno" label="Tax No "></s:textfield>
 <s:file name ="imagefile" label ="Upload Document"  />
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

 <s:submit align="center"></s:submit>
</s:form>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**client dao is**

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import model.Clientmodel;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet;

public class Clientdao {

java.sql.Connection connection =null;   
PreparedStatement pst = null;   
ResultSet rs =null;

private java.sql.Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    java.sql.Connection conn;
conn = Connectionfactory.getInstance().getConntection();    
return conn;

}

public int registration(Clientmodel model){

    int i= 0;
   try{
      String str  = "insert into " + "clientdata(Aggrement,aggrementDate,rate,maturitydate,detail,taxno,image)"+
                     "values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

       connection =getConnection();   

   pst =(PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(str);
     pst.setString(1, model.getAggrement());
     pst.setString(2, model.getDate());
     pst.setString(3, model.getRate());
     pst.setString(4, model.getMaturitydate());
     pst.setString(5, model.getDetail());
     pst.setString(6, model.getTaxno());
     pst.setBlob(7,(Blob) model.getImagefile());    

     i = pst.executeUpdate();
     System.out.println("Result " +i);
   }
  catch (SQLException se){
    se.printStackTrace();  
   }
   return i;

}
}
```

Comment: Where is the exception ?

Comment: And your action class?

Comment: You can't do that in any case, a `File` is just a filesystem pointer. You need to actually _read_ the file.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: It seems a real question to me (now, at least), voted for reopening. Btw your problem is that you need to read the File to obtain the bytes and inject it in the query, according to your database and to the library you are using to perform the insert (I use LobHandler with Spring, you will need to find another, more classic, way... search for this on google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the **ModelDriven** interface and return the object of overridden method to you model class in your Action class .